# Patterns do not behave as expected

Tags: stanford-nlp, tokenize

The actual patterns are not in English, so I created this simplified example to reproduce the problem: there are 3 levels of annotations (required for real application) and the 3rd level pattern does not work as expected. 
The phrase to be recognized is:
a b c

What I expect:

- 1st level: "a" is annotated as A, "b" is annotated as "B"
- 2nd: if there are annotations A and B, annotate them all together as AB
- 3rd: if at least one annotation AB is present and there is word "c", annotate them all together as C
  Patterns are shown below.

```
# 1.
{  pattern: (/a/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "A")) }
{  pattern: (/b/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "B")) }
# 2.
{  pattern: (([name:A]) ([name:B])), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
# 3.
{  pattern: (([name:AB]+) /c/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "C")) }
```

#1 and #2 works and "a b" are annotated:
matched token: NamedEntitiesToken{word='a' name='AB' beginPosition=0 endPosition=1}
matched token: NamedEntitiesToken{word='b' name='AB' beginPosition=2 endPosition=3}
But the #3 pattern doesn't work even though one can see that we have 2 "AB" annotated tokens and it is exactly what is expected by #3 pattern.
Even more if I change #1 to be

```
{  pattern: (/a/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
{  pattern: (/b/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
```

pattern #3 works correctly:
matched token: NamedEntitiesToken{word='a' name='C' beginPosition=0 endPosition=1}
matched token: NamedEntitiesToken{word='b' name='C' beginPosition=2 endPosition=3}
matched token: NamedEntitiesToken{word='c' name='C' beginPosition=4 endPosition=5}

I can't find any difference between matched tokens when I use

```
# In this case #3 pattern works
{  pattern: (/a/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
{  pattern: (/b/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
```

or when I use

```
# In this case #3 pattern doesn't work
# 1.
{  pattern: (/a/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "A")) }
{  pattern: (/b/), action: (Annotate($0, name, "B")) }
# 2.
{  pattern: (([name:A]) ([name:B])), action: (Annotate($0, name, "AB")) }
```

In both cases I get the same annotation, but first scenario works and the second doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 1

{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: (/a/), action: Annotate($0, ner, "A") }
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: (/b/), action: Annotate($0, ner, "B") }

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2

{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{ner: "A"}] [{ner: "B"}]), action: Annotate($0, ner, "AB") }

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 3

{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{ner: "AB"}]+ /c/), action: Annotate($0, ner, "ABC") }
```

There is a write up about TokensRegex here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Yes, just adding ENV.defaults["stage"]  has solved the problem. It is enough to add ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2 before rule #3 (the one that annotates ABC in your example). Thank you!